# ReferenceError: people is not defined in Alfresco Community

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am using Alfresco Community 5.0.d and I'm getting below error.

```
ReferenceError: people is not defined
```

For following code in people-finder.js file:

```
var currentUser = people.getPerson(person);
```

I want to use the people methods for further process. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Also my target is to get all groups for the current user and the search result too.

One way I know is making ajax call to /alfresco/service/api/people/{people}?groups=true but this is an expensive way to achieve this.

Is there an alternative to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: are you want to get current logged in user details.??

Answer (score 4):

The "people" root object as well as any other that depends on repository tier services can not be accessed directly from a web script running in Alfresco Share.

Comment: So how can I get the groups for the result that is coming search (in people-finder) ??

Comment: Share knows nothing other than what it can fetch from the Alfresco repo-tier API. You could write your own web script if you think you can do it more efficiently than the existing end point you pointed out in your post.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to get all the current user details in share webscript then you can get it using `user` Object
example:
Currently i have logged in with `admin` user

my webscript files

> test.get.js

```
        model.user=user;
```

> test.get.html.ftl

```
        ${user}
```

Output ::

> {lastName=, userStatus=null, alfUserLoaded=1489745903574,
>   userStatusTime=null,
>   alfUserGroups=GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS,GROUP_ALFRESCO_MODEL_ADMINISTRATORS,GROUP_ALFRESCO_SEARCH_ADMINISTRATORS,GROUP_EMAIL_CONTRIBUTORS,GROUP_SITE_ADMINISTRATORS,
>   firstName=Administrator,
>   userHome=workspace://SpacesStore/7338666a-7a02-4ab6-aa3b-5a46d06074ee,
>   id=admin, email=admin@alfresco.com}

list of groups in output::

> GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS,GROUP_ALFRESCO_MODEL_ADMINISTRATORS,GROUP_ALFRESCO_SEARCH_ADMINISTRATORS,GROUP_EMAIL_CONTRIBUTORS,GROUP_SITE_ADMINISTRATORS

---

### By repo webscript

if you wanted to get all the current user details in repo webscript then you can get it by using
example:
Currently i have logged in with `admin` user
 my repo webscript files

> test1.get.js

```
var users = people.getPerson(person.properties.userName);
var groups=people.getContainerGroups(users);

model["groups"] = groups;
```

> test1.get.html.ftl file

```
<#list groups as g>
   ${g.name}
</#list>
```

output::

> GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS GROUP_ALFRESCO_MODEL_ADMINISTRATORS
>   GROUP_ALFRESCO_SEARCH_ADMINISTRATORS GROUP_EMAIL_CONTRIBUTORS
>   GROUP_SITE_ADMINISTRATORS

Comment: In people-finder.js I get the result of search and I want to filter it further based on group info. I know one way to achieve is by hitting web service (Ajax to /api/people/{person}?groups=true and use the response) to get groups for each person but that's an expensive way. Is there any other way to achieve it?